# Cannot call CryptDecrypt from the WinApi crate because it could not find the module

Tags: windows, api, winapi, rust, rust-cargo

In the [documentation](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/wincrypt/fn.CryptDecrypt.html) it says that the function is in  `winapi::um::wincrypt::CryptDecrypt` but when I install the crate and bring it in my project everything works fine until I try to call the function where I get the following error message:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Could not find `wincrypt` in `um`
  --> src\main.rs:68:39
   |
68 |  let decrypted_password = winapi::um::wincrypt::CryptDecrypt(password);
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^ Could not find `wincrypt` in `um`
```

My goal is to decrypt passwords from the "Local Data" file on my computer where Chrome stores passwords. I am using the Windows `win32crypt` API binding called `winapi` in Rust. I am trying to accomplish something similar to [`chromepass`](https://github.com/hassaanaliw/chromepass) but in Rust.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of winapi? What is your Cargo.toml?

Comment: @Shepmaster yes the latest version `0.3.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [crate-level documentation](https://docs.rs/crate/winapi/0.3.4):

> ### Frequently asked questions
>
> #### Why am I getting errors about unresolved imports?
>
> Each module is gated on a feature flag, so you must enable the
>   appropriate feature to gain access to those items. For example, if you
>   want to use something from `winapi::um::winuser` you must enable the
>   `winuser` feature.

In this case, you need to add `wincrypt`:

```
[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3", features = ["wincrypt"] }
```

Comment: How do you know one must include the `wincrypt` feature? Is it explained or mapped somewhere?

Comment: @hedgar2017 I don't know how to reword the documentation to make it clearer: *Each **module** is gated on a feature flag* ...  *something from winapi::um:: **winuser*** ... *enable the **winuser** feature*.

Comment: This somehow needs to be clearer.  If I google "winapi crate um feature" I don't get anything but this helpful comment in stackoverflow.
So the first question... why have two terms "module" and "feature" if module=feature always has a 1:1 mapping.  (i.e., change the feature=[] to a module=[] in the cargo .toml or allow *either* keyword to help.

Comment: @RossYoungblood *if module=feature always has a 1:1 mapping* — That's not the case, so the point is moot. For _this specific crate_, top-level modules correspond to features, but it's not a global thing. What leads you to think it's a universal truth?

Answer (score -1):

Version 0.2.8 was too old, so when I add `wincrypt` as a feature to Cargo.toml, I got a build error.

[image]

`features = ["wincrypt"]` worked better/differently with versions 0.3.9.

Comment: Posting **code** as an **image** is not useful for search engines. Also, posting the _specific error message_ you got would also be useful for search engines.