# Is there a Rust equivalent to win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData() in Rust

Tags: winapi, encryption, rust, pywin32, rust-cargo

In Python, the `pywin32` library provides a module named `win32crypt` which has a method called `CryptUnpotectData` to decrypt Windows encrypted data by using the Windows API.

This is how I have applied it in Python:

```py
import win32crypt
# ...
password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(EncrytedPassword, None, None, None, 0)
```

I have found a binding for the [`winapi`](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/index.html) but I can't find the `CryptUnprotectData` function, the closest I found to an equivalent is [the `CryptDecrypt` function](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/wincrypt/fn.CryptDecrypt.html).

Here is my implementation of it in Rust:

```
extern crate winapi;
let decrypted_password = winapi::um::wincrypt::CryptDecrypt(/* ???? */);
```

I am not sure how to make use of this function and if it will decrypt my encrypted password string and return it. I would love if more experienced Rust users could shed some light on this for me using an example or explanation.

Comment: https://retep998.github.io/doc/crypt32/fn.CryptUnprotectData.html ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is this is it. Do you know how I can find documentation on how to use this function?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [documentation for winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/) (linked from the [crate page](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) as well as the [README](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs)), you will find a large search box:

[image: search box in docs]

If you type "CryptUnprotectData" into that search box, you will receive 3 results:

[image: search results]

Clicking on the first result will lead you to the specific function, [`CryptUnprotectData`](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/dpapi/fn.CryptUnprotectData.html). As described in [Cannot call CryptDecrypt from the WinApi crate because it could not find the module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48508952/155423), you need to use the appropriate feature flag to enable the function (`dpapi`).

As the README states:

> #### Why is there no documentation on how to use anything?
>
> This crate is nothing more than raw bindings to Windows API. If you
>   wish to know how to use the various functionality in Windows API, you
>   can look up the various items on MSDN which is full of detailed
>   documentation.

Usage of this function is [described on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx).